# Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, quorum

I am trying to perform raw transaction in quorum , but I am getting the error:

> Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits.

The code is,

```
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(rawTx).then(function(transactionReciept,error){
      if(error){
        console.log("Error occured in send Function")
        callback(error,null,null);
      }else{
        console.log("Transaction is successfull ",transactionReciept)
        transaction = JSON.stringify(transactionReciept);  
     });
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Can you post your contract and the transaction object?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript tried convert a `BigNumber` to a regular number, but the builtin number is too small. I am guessing it happens in the `console.log` when you try to print out the transactionReceipt.

Answer (score 0):

Before do anything else please be sure that provided gas is round number

Answer (score 0):

In many blogs I've found it was a Truffle version problem. Truffle v5 would make problems of this type. They suggest to downgrade to truffle@4.1.15.

This has not been so for me. I have continue to use truffle v5. I've resolved by checking my gas limit when I sent a transaction.

`gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex( gas_limit ),//The maximum gas provided for this transaction (gas limit)`

My packages version:

- Node: v8.11.4
- Truffle: 5.0.12
- Web3: 1.0.0-beta.52
- Truffle-contract: 4.0.11
- Truffle-interface-adapter@0.1.2
- │ └── web3@1.0.0-beta.37
- └── web3@1.0.0-beta.37
- Ganache-cli: v6.4.3 (ganache-core: 2.5.5)
- Ethereumjs-tx: 1.3.4

Comment: Please format this answer properly so that it's intelligible.