# Go-ethereum: Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum, quorum

I am using Quorum (geth) private blockchain and I am sporadically getting the following error:

> Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits

with the following code (using web3):

```
let contractInstance = await contract
      .deploy({
        data: data
      })
      .send({
        from: address,
        gas: 6721975,
        gasPrice: 0
      });
```

Comment: Can you post your contract? One common cause for this error is if your contract has an event defined with a dynamic sized indexed parameter. If your contract has a `bytes` or `string` as an indexed param in an event, remove `indexed`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51362535/error-number-can-only-safely-store-up-to-53-bits)